# Az CLI - Register an Azure AD B2C Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am struggling to find an Az-Cli command that will enable me to register or create an Azure AD B2C application. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

By the way, I wouldn't mind Azure Powershell as a possible solution either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the below Azure CLI cmdlets to create a app registration in Azure AD B2C tenant .

```
    az login --tenant  [myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com](http://myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/)  --allow-no-subscriptions (this cmd helped me to login to B2C without subscription)
    
    az ad app create --display-name testb2capp (this creates app in B2C)
    
    az ad app list --display-name testb2capp (Gives details of newly created app)
    
    az ad app update --id APP_ID_FROM_ABOVE_CMD --reply-urls  [https://jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)  (update any values in app)
```

Alternatively, You can use [MS Graph Create Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation and other [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#applications) operations.

For more information you can refer this [Microsoft Q&A discussion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/44395/automate-app-registration-in-b2c.html).

Comment: That is excellent @VenkateshDodda-MT. Will definitely give that a go and provide some feedback in due course. Thx.